# Google Chromecast: '403 (Forbidden)' error while streaming HLS

Tags: chromecast

I am trying to integrate the `Chromecast` into our video streaming app being developed for iOS and Android platforms. The adaptive HLS streams are playing fine with in the native players, but facing some problem when casting.

To make sure that my implementation is correct, I tried casting some sample HLS (m3u8) streams with my implementation. They works.

On debugging the cast default receiver, I got the following error.

```
==========

GET [*stream url here*] 403 (Forbidden) media_player.js:52

[162.072s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error
 cast_receiver.js:18
 ib cast_receiver.js:18
gb.Gb cast_receiver.js:18
B.log cast_receiver.js:13
E cast_receiver.js:15
Z.pa cast_receiver.js:71
Eb cast_receiver.js:23
Cb cast_receiver.js:24
(anonymous function) cast_receiver.js:21
e.onError player.js:55
h.gb media_player.js:157
Q.W media_player.js:76
Gc media_player.js:48
h.dispatchEvent media_player.js:47
Yc media_player.js:53
$c media_player.js:56
H.Ef media_player.js:54

============
```

Can anybody hint me on what is the problem? When does the receiver throw error 403?

Comment: Have you enabled CORS for your streams and are you using version 0.9.0 of the Media Player library?

Comment: Yes, CORS is enabled. Also checked with latest Media Player library and same issue exists.

Comment: The 403 is coming from the server you are using. You should determine from that server why its responding with that HTTP status code.

Comment: The m3u8 URL is authenticated (tokenised URL). The master url has token as part of the m3u8. The playlist segments has '?null=' suffixed. But the authentication is not applied to the individual segments. I have enabled the cookies in the custom receiver file. But I am not seeing any cookies saved for Chromecast device. I have debugged this through 9222 port of Chromecast ip.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions for enabling cookies: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player

Comment: Yes Leon, I have enabled the cookie that way. here is my receiver file. http://dropbox.com/s/5c84s7t51ofxdcy/cast_receiver.html. I have tried with and with out setting the request header info. Due to some proprietary information I can't share the actual m3u8 urls here. Please let me know if I can share any other information that can help identifying this issue.

Comment: Here is once sample URL showing the problem. Can anybody hint what is the problem with this URL?
http://tinyurl.com/pm4hr56

Comment: You have 2 options:
1. You should add the host.updateSegmentRequestInfo override and update the segment url in requestInfo.url as appropriate for handling the authentication. 
2. Remove the "?null=" for each segment url in the manifest. Then override host.updateManifestRequestInfo and update the requestInfo.url as appropriate for your scenario.